# ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peev

Tags: ssh

I am getting the following error using ssh to connect to a server.

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I have no problem connecting the same server from another machine and also connecting different server from the same client machine. It seems ssh works fine on both client and server but they cannot get connected. Here is the output for -vv option:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to pjd-2.ccs.neu.edu [129.10.113.66] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/rd/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rd/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rd/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rd/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rd/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rd/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rd/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/rd/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem, did you find a solution?